# Add "columns" of controls dynamically based on container height

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I'm using vs2012 (C#) for my app and I'm looking for a way to add a label and textbox to a tabPage on my form, dynamically.  But because the # of controls to be added could be larger than 10, I am also trying to add them in "columns" so the container control will only scroll horizontally, not vertically.

For instance, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
LabelControl     LabelControl     LabelControl     LabelControl
TextboxControl   TextboxControl   TextboxControl   TextboxControl

LabelControl     LabelControl     LabelControl     LabelControl
TextboxControl   TextboxControl   TextboxControl   TextboxControl

etc.
```

The "container" control is a TabPage, so I know I have to grab the height from that and use it.  I am able to get the textboxes to render but am having difficulty with the label controls being on top, then the textboxes below.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
int height = tabPageBicycle.Height;
Point startLocation = new Point(0, 0);
int previousX = 0;
int previousY = 0;
int currentX = 0;

for (int x = 0; x < 75; x++)
{
    Label label = new Label();
    TextEdit text = new TextEdit();
    label.Text = x.ToString();
    text.Text = x.ToString();

    label.Location = new Point(currentX, previousY);
    tabPageBicycle.Controls.Add(label);

    if ((height - previousY) < text.Height)
    {
        currentX += 100;
        previousY = 0;
    }

    text.Location = new Point(currentX + text.Height + 5, previousY + 50);
    previousX = text.Location.X;
    previousY = text.Location.Y;
    tabPageBicycle.Controls.Add(text);
}
```

Any clues as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up figuring it out, after taking it line-by-line and seeing what was being done in the loop.  Here's the final code I used....as always, I'm open to suggestions/comments/etc. on how to make it better/more efficient.

```
int labelY = 0;
int textY = 0;
int startX = 5;
int startY = 5;
int height = tabPageBicycle.Height;
Point startLocation = new Point(0, 0);

for (int x = 0; x < 75; x++)
{
    Label label = new Label();
    TextEdit text = new TextEdit();
    label.AutoSize = true;
    label.Text = x.ToString();
    text.Text = x.ToString();

    //Determine if the next set of controls will be past the height of the container.
    //If so, start on the next column (change X).
    if ((height - textY) < ((label.Height + 10) + text.Height))
    {
        startX += 125;
        labelY = 0;
    }

    //Start of new column.
    if (labelY == 0)
        label.Location = new Point(startX, startY);
    else
        label.Location = new Point(startX, textY + label.Height + 10);

    tabPageBicycle.Controls.Add(label);
    labelY = label.Location.Y;
    textY = labelY + 15;

    text.Location = new Point(startX, textY);
    textY = text.Location.Y;
    tabPageBicycle.Controls.Add(text);
}
```

and the results:
[image]

I hope it helps someone else out!